# Overriding the "Open" Menu Item in elFinder

Tags: elfinder

I'm using [elFinder](http://elfinder.org) to access some stored files on a website, but the files themselves aren't directly accessible.  Instead, I request them through a particular controller action.  So I override the `getFileCallback` in elFinder to use a custom URL:

```
getFileCallback: function (file) {
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("File", "Home")' + '?path=' + encodeURI(file);
}
```

This works great for double-clicking on a file.  However, if I just select the file and use the Open button in the elFinder toolbar, this callback isn't used.  Instead it opens a popup and tries to use the default URL, which results in a 404 error.

Is there a way to override the behavior of the Open button in the toolbar?  I've been trying various things in the [Client event API](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-event-API) or in the [commands options](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-configuration-options#wiki-commandsOptions), but can't seem to find anything that modifies the Open behavior.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up doing was overriding the open function entirely:

```
elFinder.prototype.commands.open = function () {
    // custom code
};
```

(Just do this in a `script` block after loading the elFinder code.)

I can't say if it's ideal, and it will take some tweaking if there are major upgrades to elFinder, but it's definitely doing the job.  (Going from this, I also started overriding some of the other functions which use the URL, such as the anchor tag in the info pop-up.)